# Explaining allene IR stretching frequency

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

So I was comparing the IR stretch frequency of ethyne, ethene and allene. Of course triple bond is stiffer than double bond so ethyne has a higher stretch frequency. The problem then is where allene sits when compared to these two. I guess it should be the lowest because I just think of the cumulated double bonds as serial spring, which should give lower spring stiffness than only one double bond in ethene. Obviously, I'm wrong... It turns out allene IR stretch frequency is in the middle of ethene and ethyne.  I wonder how might we explain that. Thanks!

Comment: There are two normal modes for the along-axis stretch in allene. Are you thinking about the right one?

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit? I’m not sure which two mode you are talking about

Comment: The symmetrical stretching mode won't participate in IR spectroscopy just like that of $CO_2$ but the asymmetrical stretching mode would.

Comment: @SurajS okay, but I’m asking about how to explain the frequency

Comment: @SurajS we don’t cover stretching mode in the intro org class

Comment: @Macrophage $$\bar{\nu} = \frac{1}{200\pi c}\sqrt{\frac{k}{\mu}} $$ Above is the formula based on Newtonian mechanics for calculating stretching frequency. So, we can't come to a conclusion just by comparing the spring constant $k$. We should also consider the reduced mass $\mu$ for a linear three-body system in case of an allene which I'll let you know if I get it. Alkene and alkyne can be compared just by looking at the spring constant since reduced mass is the same in both the cases but the situation of allene is a bit different.

Comment: Thank you, I will be very interested it if you can explain allene's frequency with just that formula, which we did learn in our organic chemistry course.